# In Mac OS X Terminal, what are the best colors, fonts, etc. to use?

Tags: macos, terminal

What is a Good/Best Terminal setting? I had my terminal (Mac OSX) set on Homebrew but it's kind of boring! What setting do you guys use out there? Are there any i can import? Any that you would recommend?

Love to know what colors, fonts, font size you use out there that are easy on the eyes?

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Not really programming related (it's all opinion, no fact) but Red Sands is my favorite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the Pro settings with minimal changes, and [Visor](http://visor.binaryage.com/) because I really like having instant access to the terminal without alt-tabbing.

Answer (score 3):

I really love the [Solarized color scheme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized). I only changed the colors for marked text which were barely visible.

Also, I am not using the default Terminal.app, but [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/) which has some nifty features.

Comment: Yep Solarized dark.  I set up eclipse to solarized dark and then when setting up the colors in terminal use the magnifying glass feature to sample the actual colors so they match perfectly.  The default terminal fonts monaco, menlo and andale mono.  A good source for color ideas is go to the eclipse color theme web site and browse their colors...again then just use the color sample magnifying glass in the color picker.

Answer (score 2):

I was also bored with default terminal settings for a long and after trying tried various combinations, I found the following settings are best suited for day to day programming usage:

**Mac's Terminal > Preferences**

```
Monaco, Regular, Font Size 14.
```

PFB - A sample terminal image for the look and feel.

[image]

Comment: Using the exact settings here...