# OS X GNU-Screen Breaking Coloring

Tags: bash, shell, colors, terminal, gnu-screen

I've defined coloring in my `.bash_profile` on my Mac OS X as follows:

```
# ls color alias
alias ls='ls -G'

# Colours
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
BLACK="\[\033[0;30m\]"
DARK_GRAY="\[\033[1;30m\]"
LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
WHITE="\[\033[0;37m\]"
RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
RED_BOLD="\[\033[1;31m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
YELLOW_BOLD="\[\033[1;33m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
GREEN_BOLD="\[\033[1;32m\]"
BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
BLUE_BOLD="\[\033[1;34m\]"
CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
CYAN_BOLD="\[\033[1;36m\]"
PURPLE="\[\033[0;35m\]"
PURPLE_BOLD="\[\033[1;35m\]"
BROWN="\[\033[0;33m\]"

# Terminal colours
export CLICOLOR=1
export XTERM=xterm-color
export LSCOLORS=BxFxCxDxGxegedabagacad
```

I've noticed also that when I use GNU-Screen (which is always), the coloring is very different. The red turns into yellow, orange turns into yellow, and anything between quotations turns from purple to green. This appears to happen in Emacs mostly since Emacs displays all kinds of different colors.

I also have a ps1 prompt which also displays my current `git` branch in the directory. This does not change its color.

My first question is, where are those colors defined? Why and how does GNU-Screen change the colors? What's the best way to go about coloring my terminal?

My second question is, when I copied my `.bash_profile` from my Mac OS X into a CentOS server I SSH into, the coloring was not the same. Does Mac use a different color code than CentOS? If so, how can I standardize my coloring in both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your native terminal emulation and what screen thinks it is may not agree on the number of colors supported.

- What is the value of `TERM` before and after starting `screen`?
- What is the output of `tput colors` in either case?

Report these for both the server and the Max OS terminal.

---

Thanks for reporting that.  The server assumes there's support for more colors than 
OSX Terminal physically supports.

Try to overrule TERM on CentOS with `TERM=xterm-color`, or remove any TERM setting from your rc files/profile on linux, and let the OS pick up the proper value from ssh.

Comment: `$TERM` on Mac OS and the server before screen is: `$TERM
-bash: xterm-256color: command not found`. `tput colors` on my Mac OS terminal is 8, and on my server is 256.

Comment: It looks like OSX Terminal is limited to eight colors.  Check out [In Mac OS X Terminal, what are the best colors, fonts, etc. to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186886/in-mac-os-x-terminal-what-are-the-best-colors-fonts-etc-to-use) for a recommendation of [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/), which appears to support 256 colors.

Comment: Oh - so the coloring I am seeing on my Mac is not the real colors that are set? They're just converted since my Mac only supports 8 colors? Are you aware how to get `Emacs` to color languages on its own? In the 256 color terminal, Emacs colors are extremely annoying in `cc-mode`. The comments are actually divided into two colors, the `//` in green and the actual comment string in pink. Is that normal?

Comment: I've got no clue about what's normal for Emacs here. There's one little thing that might make a difference: toggle the ANSI colors setting in OSX Terminal Preferences.  But ultimately, set TERM to something that matches the OSX Terminal capabilities, and no more.

Comment: My OS X terminal is declared as a `xterm-256color` terminal. How is that even available as an option when the terminal only supports 8 colors?

Comment: @Darksky Which OS X? My wife has a mac, with snow leopard. xterm-color is the last choice.

Comment: OS X Mountain Lion. I think xterm-256color was introduced with Lion.

Comment: Terminal and vim on MacOS X (at least 10.8 and 10.9) both support 256 colors and report xterm-256color as the terminal type. However, the version of screen that ships with OS X does *not* support 256 colors. Ive verified this by running a Perl script to output all the color codes both inside and outside screen - I see 256 colors outside and only 16 (8 X 2 brightness levels) inside. From what Ive read online one potential fix is to download and build your own copy of screen - it has support for configuring the build to use 256 colors but Apple didn't choose to.

Comment: (cont'd from above): I dislike having to download and build from source without using something like Homebrew to manage but the main Homebrew repo has screen blacklisted, BUT there is dupes repo available that has the build, so in Homebrew you can just do `brew install homebrew/dupes/screen` and enjoy using a 256-color version of screen.